# Kali Linux Live USB (with Persistence) Boots To Blinking Cursor After Unknown Filesystem

Tags: linux, boot, usb, partitioning, filesystems

I am aware that many people have this problem, but none of them seem to have the same details as me. I am attempting to create a live USB with persistance for Kali Linux (32-bit). I have followed the necessary steps:

1. Installed the ISO file from kali.org
2. Verified the sha256sum of the ISO file
3. Used GParted to format my drive to FAT32
4. Used GParted to create a persistence (ext4) partition
5. Used `sudo dd if=/home/arctic_hen7/Downloads/kali-linux-2017.2-i386.iso of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M`
    to extract the contents of the ISO file to my USB

This is when I noticed that after I went back into GParted to close it, the filesystem of the Kali Live partition (not the persistance) had become unknown (and a red exclamation mark sign appeared next to the partition name). Also, when I went into the persistence partition from Nautilus, it had a lost+found directory. I tried booting it like this (after adjusting my BIOS settings), but I was presented with a black screen and a flashing white underscore cursor in the top-left corner of the screen. I waited, but it did not boot. I then booted back into Ubuntu and tried the whole process again (but with the same ISO file), but I also deleted the lost+found directory in the persistance partition. I tried booting but was met with the same issue. My system specifications:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (alongside Windows Vista (which I never use))
Vaio VGN-Z46GD (quite old)
Intel Centrino 2
Insyde H2O BIOS

I hope this helps.

Edit: I have managed to fix the problem and now have Kali Linux 32-bit with persistence on a 32GB USB flash drive. Please see my answer below for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am not sure what the original error was (it may have been to do with remounting..), but I installed a program called UNetBootIn and followed the instructions on their website (https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) to download the program through the terminal. I then used it to extract the Kali ISO file onto my USB (not using their persistence option), and after checking GParted, found that the filesystem was still FAT32. I then resized the partition and created an ext4 partition with the 'persistence' label (to use for persistence). I then saved my changes, mounted the USB drive by ejecting it and putting it back in again, and then booted to it. I then followed the instruction on the website I was following (https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/install-kali-live-usb-drive-with-persistence-optional-0162253/) and I then had persistence working. I hope this helps all those who have had a similar problem to myself.